# Shell script to make directories and subdirectories with variable names

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to create script to be run by cron to create multiple folders with subfolders.

```
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
IP_ADDR=`ifconfig | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | sed -n 's/.*inet addr:\([0-9.]\+\)\s.*/\1/p'`
/bin/mkdir -p /mnt/db-backup/12/$DATE/$IP_ADDR/
```

If i run this script manually everything is created as expected. When script is ran by cron subdirectory $IP_ADDR is not created and there is no errors.

Comment: To find the problem you could change your script to save the output of ifconfig in a file. And also  the variable IP_ADDR.

Comment: both return correct values: 10.1.1.3

Comment: As an aside, `grep -v foo | sed 's/bar/baz/'`is a [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) and is better written `sed -n '/foo/!s/bar/baz/p'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `/sbin` is not part of the PATH for the environment that the cron job runs under. You should specify the full path for the `ifconfig` command:

```
IP_ADDR=$(/sbin/ifconfig | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | sed -n 's/.*inet addr:\([0-9.]\+\)\s.*/\1/p')
```

It's also better practice (in general) to use `$()` for command substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use debug mode :

```
set -x
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
IP_ADDR=`ifconfig | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | sed -n 's/.*inet addr:\([0-9.]\+\)\s.*/\1/p'`
/bin/mkdir -p /mnt/db-backup/12/$DATE/$IP_ADDR/
set +x
```

Then, redirect the output of your cron to a file and have a look, you should find useful information in it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not far off, but there are several ordering caveats that could cause problems. Many systems have different formats for the `ifconfig` output line. Some with `inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`, others with `inet addr:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`. (those are the two most common). You may also need to handle the case where there are multiple wired inet interfaces (2+ NICs in the box). However, if you have only 1 NIC, you could try the following to handle the common `ifconfig` formats:

```
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
IP_ADDR=$(ifconfig | 
          grep -v '127.0.0.1' | 
          grep -E 'inet[ ](addr:)*[0-9]{1,3}([.][0-9]{1,3}){3}' | 
          sed -e 's/^.*inet \(addr:\)*//' -e 's/ .*$//')
/bin/mkdir -p /mnt/db-backup/12/$DATE/$IP_ADDR/
```

or with `IP_ADDR` written as one line:

```
IP_ADDR=$(ifconfig | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | grep -E 'inet[ ](addr:)*[0-9]{1,3}([.][0-9]{1,3}){3}' | sed -e 's/^.*inet \(addr:\)*//' -e 's/ .*$//')
```